# What type is this aircraft, appearing in the movie "Kingsman"?

Tags: aircraft-identification

In a scene of the movie *[Kingsman: The Secret Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsman:_The_Secret_Service)* the young aspiring agents have to skydive from an airplane. I didn't recognise it: which airplane is it (assuming it actually exists)?

I could only find a picture [from inside](http://www.normankent.com/img/s10/v98/p459364338-3.jpg) and one [from below](http://www.normankent.com/img/s6/v149/p790102179-3.jpg).

Comment: Fortunately the one from below includes a (barely legible) [registration](http://jetphotos.net/showphotos.php?offset=15&where=|||||||1|||||G-BEOL|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||).

Comment: To follow up with that, here's more photos of that actual aircraft: http://www.airliners.net/search/photo.search?regsearch=G-BEOL

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That distinctly squarish shape looks like a [Short SC-7 Skyvan 3-100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_SC.7_Skyvan), especially since the registration on the photo from below is visible: [G-BEOL](http://www.airliners.net/search/photo.search?regsearch=G-BEOL). 
 -

[image]

<sup>(Image Source: [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Short_skyvan_sc-7_g-beol_cotswoldairshow_2010_arp.jpg) - Author: Adrian Pingstone)</sup>

Comment: Youtube: [Short Skyvan flight over Spa for parachutist dropping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrm7DL541V0)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, this is a Skyvan. It was built in Belfast at the Short Brothers facility, near to the then RAF Sydenham - now George Best Airport. My father worked for Shorts as a senior design engineer. In the late 1960s I was able to visit the assembly floor. I was aged nine or ten. I saw part-completed early variant Skyvans. from time to time, I saw the finished planes over Belfast Lough as they were subjected to test flights.

Answer (score 0):

It is the Shorts SC-7. You can see the short nose compared to the C-23 Sherpa. I too thought C-23 because I worked on them in the US Air Force.
[image: Kingsman_SC-7_vs_C-23]